# Vue plugin, adding global component which takes data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue plugins so that user can access a global component once registering the global component and configuring it inside `Vue.use`. For this I need to pass some data from `Vue.use()` to `Component.vue`.

Take a look at the following code:

```
Vue.use(MyPlugin, { data: true });
```

the code of `MyPlugin` is

import Plugin from './plugin';

```
const IconPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    console.log(options); // Here I can see {data: true}
    Vue.component('GlobalComponent', Icon);
  },
};
```

Now I need to pass this options variable to the component. So that a user whenever use

```
<GlobalComponent />
```

`{data: true}` should always be there.

Basically, that is a configuration which user is passing and the further component computation will be dependent on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Vue.extend` to extend components

```js
var Icon = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'fooooo',
      bar: 'barr'
    }
  },
  template: '<div><button @click="doFooStuff">{{foo}}</button><button @click="doBarStuff">{{bar}}</button></div>',
  methods: {
    doBarStuff: function() {
      console.log(this.foo, this.bar)
    },
    doFooStuff: function() {
      console.log(this.foo)
    }
  }
})


const IconPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    // console.log(options);
    // normalize data (select only props you want)
    var data = Object.assign({}, options);
    var NewIcon = Icon.extend({
      data: function() {
        return data;
      }
    })
    Vue.component('GlobalComponent', NewIcon);
  },
};

Vue.use(IconPlugin, {
  foo: 'FOOO'
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Icon
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <icon></icon>
  <global-component></global-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to take a look at the [component guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). It would seem that you want to merge the data with where you are passing `Icon`.

Comment: This should rather be a comment.. But yes i want to pass options in Vue.component method